# Crawl error (Response Code 404)

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, 404

Recently I've built my first website using WordPress and I'm having some trouble indexing it. As you guys can see, the site is working (http://contacontente.com), even though it doesn't have much content yet.

I've uploaded a sitemap to the Search Console and Google has already indexed my only post. However, I haven't been able to index my homepage. Whenever I try to fetch it as Google, I get the "Not Found" message (see image below). I'm not sure what's happening, since the site can be found when you go through the direct link.

[image: Not found error]

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a 404.   You have a server misconfiguration.  The page appears to have content, but is being delivered with a 404 error code rather than 200 OK.

Whatever is going wrong is happening server side.  I don't have any way of figuring that out for you without access to your server.   Try looking for problems in your Apache *error_log*.

Here is how I test it:

```
$ curl --head http://contacontente.com/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 08 May 2017 18:29:17 GMT
Server: Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Link: <http://contacontente.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=covah59qj2d19sq4qad2t0rf47; path=/
Set-Cookie: wfvt_4093780464=5910b8fdb3293; expires=Mon, 08-May-2017 18:59:17 GMT; path=/; httponly
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Also Firefox Network debug tool:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Stephen. Thanks for the quick response. I'm sorry if this sounds as a stupid question, but as I said, this is my first website so I don't know that much. To be honest, I'm not even sure where to find this error log. I've logged into the cPanel and searched for it, but without success. Could you help me on that? Thanks!

Comment: The apache error logs are usually in  `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` or `/var/log/apache2/error_log`.   cPanel should have a section for viewing them under **metrics** --> **errors**:  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/stats-logging/how-to-view-cpanel-error-logs

Comment: Thank you. I found the error log through the metrics menu, as suggested. The error I'm getting is the following: [Mon May 08 18:29:28 2017] [error] [client 189.19.75.55] File does not exist: /home/contaela/public_html/home. How can this be? How can my homepage display content if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but: at first my site was contacontente.com/wp. The contacontente.com/ domain was giving me an error. Then I read a few posts a found a way to enable it (and now we see some content in it). It's possible that this change caused the error we are seeing now.

Comment: I'm not sure how your content is being served ever with the 404 error.   It sounds like your hosting company configured *home.html* to be the default page rather than *index.html*   You could make sure that your *.htaccess* file has a line like `DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php` to set it back to the default and work properly with WordPress.

Comment: You could edit your question to explain the changes you made that could have broken it.

Comment: To change the homepage domain, I've followed the "Method I" explained in https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory. My _.htaccess_ is just like the one in the example, but using my own domain.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong with that.   Try the `DirectoryIndex`.

Comment: Is there a specific place I've got to write it in the htaccess file? Either before or after something?

Comment: At the top should work fine.  It shouldn't conflict with anything.

Comment: The error persists. I've written that Directory line first in the .htaccess in the root folder, then in the .htaccess in the wp folder and then in both and nothing changed. In the second .htaccess file I found some text about a plugin I installed when I first made the site (WP Super Cache). I later deactivated it - could it be a cause of our problem?